# Change image on scroll position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to recreate a section from this website: https://calendly.com/. Specifically the "Share your Calendly availability with others" section.

The animation should be that the left section with heading and content is scrollable and the image should fade out in the next image on scroll. I've created a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/mitchellsl-the-bashful/full/oNMvKJp) but I just can't get it working correctly.

```js
var wrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper");

function checkInView() {
  wrappers.forEach(function(wrapper) {
    var bounds = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (bounds.top < window.innerHeight && bounds.bottom > 0) {
      wrapper.classList.add("in-view");
    } else {
      wrapper.classList.remove("in-view");
    }
  });
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var imageColumn = wrappers[0].querySelector(".image-column");
  imageColumn.style.opacity = 1;
});

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  checkInView();

  wrappers.forEach(function(wrapper) {
    var scrollPos = window.scrollY;
    var wrapperPos = wrapper.offsetTop;
    var wrapperHeight = wrapper.offsetHeight;
    var imageColumn = wrapper.querySelector(".image-column");
    if (scrollPos > wrapperPos && scrollPos < wrapperPos + wrapperHeight) {
      imageColumn.style.transform =
        "translateY(" + (scrollPos - wrapperPos) + "px)";
      imageColumn.classList.add("fade-out");
    } else {
      imageColumn.classList.remove("fade-out");
      imageColumn.classList.add("fade-in");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  visibility: visible
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 70vh;
}

.wrapper {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.wrapper.in-view {
  visibility: visible;
}

.text-column {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image-column-inner {
  width: 50%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: calc(50% - 35vh);
  height: 70vh;
}

.image-column {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.8/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text-column">
      <h1>Share your Calendly availability with others</h1>
      <p>
        Grow your business with scheduling automation. Simply email, text, or add your Calendly availability to your website – and watch prospects and recruits book high-value meetings with you.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-column-inner">
      <div class="image-column">
        <img src="https://images.ctfassets.net/k0lk9kiuza3o/7mkknkKmPsEGwaB5mdt60t/33d742a897f87e8f6f5e11df85659960/Calendly-Email-Embed.png?w=1140&h=930&q=50&fm=webp" alt="image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text-column">
      <h1>Schedule as a team
      </h1>
      <p>
        Calendly adapts to both you and your team's scheduling preferences. Co-host a client call with a colleague, email reminders and follow-ups, and integrate everything with your preferred software tools.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-column-inner">
      <div class="image-column">
        <img src="https://images.ctfassets.net/k0lk9kiuza3o/7mkknkKmPsEGwaB5mdt60t/33d742a897f87e8f6f5e11df85659960/Calendly-Email-Embed.png?w=1140&h=930&q=50&fm=webp" alt="image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text-column">
      <h1>Hit your number</h1>
      <p>
        High-value meetings are the lifeblood of your business. Increase revenue, retain customers, and land recruits with the #1 scheduling automation platform.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="image-column-inner">
      <div class="image-column">
        <img src="https://images.ctfassets.net/k0lk9kiuza3o/7mkknkKmPsEGwaB5mdt60t/33d742a897f87e8f6f5e11df85659960/Calendly-Email-Embed.png?w=1140&h=930&q=50&fm=webp" alt="image">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take care to format the code in your questions properly. In this case, as you already had the Codepen, I transposed it from there.

Comment: What you could investigate is an intersection observer... this allows you to determine what is in the DOM and when it enters / leaves the visble viewport and so update the src of the image ....

Answer (score 0):

```js
const img = document.querySelector(".container img");
const textOne = document.querySelector(".one");
const textTwo = document.querySelector(".two");
const textThree = document.querySelector(".three");

function isInViewport(el) {
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    if (isInViewport(textOne) == true) {
        img.src = "https://images.ctfassets.net/k0lk9kiuza3o/7mkknkKmPsEGwaB5mdt60t/33d742a897f87e8f6f5e11df85659960/Calendly-Email-Embed.png?w=1140&h=930&q=50&fm=webp";
    }
    if (isInViewport(textTwo) == true) {
        img.src = "https://images.ctfassets.net/k0lk9kiuza3o/6XqS7MbsZB4a08zAUxOHde/033649d82a01b51bbc080b037aac0206/Calendly-Round-Robin.png?w=1140&h=931&q=50&fm=webp";
    }
    if (isInViewport(textThree) == true) {
        img.src = "https://images.ctfassets.net/k0lk9kiuza3o/ImJSAqUd3vtZlQiEiyWXH/a6a23c23b5d4fdb5173b5a43c48de78a/Calendly-Graph.png?w=1140&h=930&q=50&fm=webp";
    }
});
```

```css
*, *::after, *::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;  
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


body {
    padding: 0 100px;
}
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 200%;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 600px auto auto auto;
}
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    top: 50px;
}

.text {
    height: 400px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

.other {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
  <h2>We make scheduling for you easier than ever</h2>
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <div class="text one">
        <h3>Share your Calendly availability with others</h3>
        <p>Grow your business with scheduling automation. Simply email, text, or add your Calendly availability to your website – and watch prospects and recruits book high-value meetings with you.</p>
        <a href="">Learn more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="text two">
        <h3>Schedule as a team</h3>
        <p>Calendly adapts to both you and your team's scheduling preferences. Co-host a client call with a colleague, email reminders and follow-ups, and integrate everything with your preferred software tools.</p>
        <a href="">Learn more</a>
      </div>
      <div class="text three">
        <h3>Hit your number</h3>
        <p>High-value meetings are the lifeblood of your business. Increase revenue, retain customers, and land recruits with the #1 scheduling automation platform.</p>
        <a href="">Learn more</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <img src="https://images.ctfassets.net/k0lk9kiuza3o/7mkknkKmPsEGwaB5mdt60t/33d742a897f87e8f6f5e11df85659960/Calendly-Email-Embed.png?w=1140&h=930&q=50&fm=webp" alt="">
  </div>

  <div class="other"></div>
```